# Angular5 Service Worker update(SWUpdate) not detecting on firefox. Working on chrome

Tags: angular, firefox, caching, angular-service-worker

I am using `Angular5` and `angular service worker`.

I `cached` some data and some assets and everything is working fine as expected and even deployed the code.

Now, if I update some code and deploy again, the **`service worker` doesnot get updated.**

So, I had gone through [Angular service worker](https://angular.io/guide/service-worker-communications) link and I Implemened `SwUpdate service`.

Here is my code:

**I created a service and called it in App Component**

```
import { Injectable, NgZone } from '@angular/core';
import { interval } from 'rxjs/observable/interval';
import { SwUpdate } from '@angular/service-worker';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Rx';


@Injectable()
export class ServiceWorkerService {

  constructor(updates: SwUpdate, ngZone: NgZone) {
    console.log('Servicee worker update called');
    updates.available.subscribe(event => {
      console.log('current version is', event.current);
      console.log('available version is', event.available);
      updates.activateUpdate().then(() => document.location.reload());
    });
    updates.activated.subscribe(event => {
      console.log('old version was', event.previous);
      console.log('new version is', event.current);
    });
    ngZone.runOutsideAngular(() => {
      interval(6000).subscribe(() => {
        console.log('Inside Interval')
        ngZone.run(() => updates.checkForUpdate());
      });
    });
  }
}
```

What the above code does:

- Whenever a new code is deployed, the old serviceworker detects it.
- Then it `subscribes` to `updates.available` event.
- We listen to that event and er reload the page.

**Issue:**

> Now, the issue is, it is working perfectly on chrome. **But not in 
>   firefox**. In firefox, the code is not comming inside
>   `updates.available.subscribe`

Comment: I have the same issue. Chrome is fine. Not for Firefox mobile browser.

Comment: did you manage to resolve this?

Comment: Experiencing this same problem on Chrome. "update.available.subscribe" never reports an update. I am using  "@angular/service-worker": "^8.2.14". Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 13):

I had this same issue and was able to fix it by registering the service worker in `main.ts`:

```
platformBrowserDynamic().bootstrapModule(AppModule).then(() => {
  if ('serviceWorker' in navigator && environment.production) {
    navigator.serviceWorker.register('/ngsw-worker.js');
  }
}).catch(err => console.log(err));
```

I also created a Service worker service to notify the user when there is a new update available:

[image]

If you are interested in how my service worker service looks, you can see the code [**here**](https://gist.github.com/michaeldoye/d48a45c2f3f634cc215c183929406bd0).

You can also check if any errors have been logged by visiting `yourdomain.com/ngsw/state`

Comment: Your answer is helpful. Thanks @Und3rTow

Comment: you fix it by registering the service worker in main.ts. Then what about in app.module.ts, as with every angular-cli project there is   ServiceWorkerModule.register('/ngsw-worker.js', {enabled: environment.production}) this. Did you remove this?

Comment: I have kept it in place as `ServiceWorkerModule` is needed to use `SwUpdate`.

Comment: Even with this, Firefox works only intermittently for me. Other browsers are fine.

Comment: This fixed my Angular service worker on both firefox desktop & iOS (was already fine on Chrome Desktop).  Thanks!

Comment: This works fine but registering the service worker in main.ts breaks **server side rendering**. If I remove this ssr works fine. Any help?

Comment: @amansoni211 I haven't really used SSR much, but you could probably try registering the service worker in your `index.html` (kinda dirty but might stop it from breaking SSR)

Comment: I found the **ServiceWorkerModule.register**-methode has a parameter **registrationStrategy** wich defaults to only attach the serviceworker once tha application stabelizes - which i assume to mean an empty call-stack - and is blocked by things like and indefinitely running **interval** or similar... you might wanna use 'registerImmediately' or one of the other options: https://angular.io/api/service-worker/SwRegistrationOptions#registrationStrategy